# JADE: Scheduling behaviours

Tags: java, agents-jade, multi-agent

I am teaching myself JADE and was wondering whether there is an easy way to schedule behaviours in such a way that one agent behaviour won't be executed until all other agents have previously finished their behaviour cycles?

For example, assuming  I have a set of behaviours (A, B, C) that I add to each agent, however I do not want any of the other behaviours (B,C) to execute until ALL agents have completed behaviour A. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can orchestrate such behavior exchanging messages among agents. Here it is a paper with a more sophisticated protocol that can avoid deadlocks in your MAS: http://www.db-thueringen.de/servlets/DerivateServlet/Derivate-19681/ESM2009_S337-341.pdf